# . Find the partial fraction decomposition of the following rational function.

Tags: factoring, partial-fractions

Find the PFD of the folowing:

$$\frac{x^6-x^5+48x^3-53x^2+99x+48}{x^5-2x^4+2x^3-4x^2+x-2}$$
Initially I used long division and got $$x+1+\frac{50(x^3-x^2+2x+1)}{x^5-2x^4+2x^3-4x^2+x-2}$$ I then used trial and error to factor the denominator as:
$$x+1+\frac{50(x^3-x^2+2x+1)}{x^5-2x^4+2x^3-4x^2+x-2}=x+1+\frac{50(x^3-x^2+2x+1)}{(x-2)(x^4+2x^2+1)}$$
How do I factor the second part of the denominator?

Comment: Is this a scan of someone else's question?

Comment: Nop, i find it easier to code on latex then just import the image :)

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the denominator factors as
$$
(x^4 + 2x^2 + 1) = ((x^2)^2 + 2(x^2) + 1) = (x^2 + 1)^2
$$
Therefore, your partial fraction decomposition is of the form
$$
\frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1} + \frac{Dx+E}{(x^2+1)^2}
$$